# Docker SDK for Python- How keep container up not in interactive mode

Tags: python, docker

Im trying to start a container and keep it up but not in interactive mode so it will still be returned as an output by the docker ps command
its something like: docker run -d alpine sleep 50 
I couldn't find any reference how to do it using Docker SDK for Python
Please advise

Comment: Can you describe your python workload?  Web server?

Comment: First im checking if there are containers up. in case there are im stopping them. than im trying to bring up only my container and to run get confirmation that it is the only container that is up using: client.containers.list(). than im suppose to bring up my container not in interactive mode. its not on a web server

Comment: I could do it using: subprocess.call(['docker run -d alpine sleep 60'], shell=True) .still i prefer to do it using the docker SDK for Python (if there is a way)

Answer (score -1):

the run method for the container object in the Python Docker SDK has a boolean parameter called **detach**, I think setting it to true will result in that container running in the background

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

Example:

```
import docker
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
client.containers.run('nginx',detach=True)
```

Comment: Already tried this. in this case it will run and immediately exit the container

Comment: import subprocess
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
running_containers = client.containers.list()
for rc in running_containers:
    rc.stop()
subprocess.call(['docker run -t -d alpine'], shell= True)

Comment: Hi, I've just edited the answer to show an example. The problem is that your are running an image which entrypoint is not running forever. Try it with another image as nginx or add an entrypoint that doesn't end